# Is there a procedure for migrating azure logic apps from one subscription to new subscription using arm templates/ terraform / powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, azure-logic-apps

0

I want to migrate azure logic apps from old subscription to new subscription. Please help with the steps for migration using using arm templates/ terraform / powershell script.

Please help me in this regard.

I want to migrate azure logic apps from old subscription to new subscription. Please help with the steps for migration using using arm templates/ terraform / powershell script.

Please help me in this regard.